# How to change a colour of breakpoint in NetBeans 8.0?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

When I set breakpoint in NetBeans i have trouble of reading it, because it is high lighted in some very dark colour, burugundy I suppose.

[image]

I have tried in **Tools->Options->Fonts&Colours->Annotations->Breakpoint**, but still nothing has been changed.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case, I had to:

1. Remove the breakpoints.
2. Make the change.
3. Restart Netbeans.
4. Re-apply breakpoints.